# Resource with id [ApiGatewayLambdaS3Event] is invalid. property BucketName not defined for resource of type S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sam

I am adding an S3 event in my sam.yaml file to trigger the lambda function when a file is added inside the bucket.

The trigger for these functions that I shall be making will be for existing S3 buckets. Would I be able to create the triggers for existing buckets using SAM or would I need to create the triggers manually?

However, I am getting the following error

```
Resource with id [ApiGatewayLambdaS3Event] is invalid. property BucketName not defined for resource of type S3
```

Here is my template.yaml file that I have created with all the lambda functions and triggers I am trying to create.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: CD Demo Lambda
Resources:
  CDDemoLambda:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      CodeUri: ./FunctionOne
      FunctionName: CDDemoLambda
      Description: 'Lambda function for CD Demo Test'
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 30
      Events:
        getAZsAPI:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /getazs
            Method: get
            
  HelloWorld:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      AutoPublishAlias: qaTest
      Handler: qa-hello-world.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      CodeUri: ./FunctionTwo
      FunctionName: HelloWorld
      Description: 'Hello WOrld'
      
  ApiGatewayLambda:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      AutoPublishAlias: apigateway
      Handler: lambdafunctionthree.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      FunctionName: ApiGatewayLambda
      CodeUri: ./FunctionThree
      Description: 'Hello WOrld'
```

What changes do I need to make to add an S3 event trigger to be created along with my lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-use-app-spec.html)

You can further mix and match what kind of events you want your lambda to be invoked.

```
    AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
    Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
    Description: CD Demo Lambda
    Resources:
    CDDemoLambda:
        Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
        Properties:
        Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
        Runtime: python3.6
        CodeUri: ./FunctionOne
        FunctionName: CDDemoLambda
        Description: 'Lambda function for CD Demo Test'
        MemorySize: 128
        Timeout: 30
        Events:
            getAZsAPI:
            Type: Api
            Properties:
                Path: /getazs
                Method: get
    SrcBucket:
        Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'

    HelloWorld:
        Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
        Properties:
        AutoPublishAlias: qaTest
        Handler: qa-hello-world.lambda_handler
        Runtime: python3.6
        CodeUri: ./FunctionTwo
        FunctionName: HelloWorld
        Description: 'Hello WOrld'
        Policies:
            S3ReadPolicy:
            BucketName: !Ref SrcBucket
            Events:
                CreateThumbnailEvent:
                Type: S3
                Properties:
                    Bucket: !Ref SrcBucket
                    Events: s3:ObjectCreated:*

    LambdaInvokePermission:
        Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Permission'
        Properties:
        FunctionName: !GetAtt HelloWorld.Arn
        Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
        Principal: 's3.amazonaws.com'
        SourceAccount: !Sub ${AWS::AccountId}
        SourceArn: !GetAtt SrcBucket.Arn

    ApiGatewayLambda:
        Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
        Properties:
        AutoPublishAlias: apigateway
        Handler: lambdafunctionthree.lambda_handler
        Runtime: python3.6
        FunctionName: ApiGatewayLambda
        CodeUri: ./FunctionThree
        Description: 'Hello WOrld'
```

Comment: hi thanks, really appreciate it.  would I be able to use my existing bucket or i have to mention a new bucket name?